# connecting to mysql database on lan

Tags: c#

i need to run my c# app on a LAN.the database is hosted on my friend's laptop using mysql in xampp.

in my connection class, this method returns the connection string.

```
        public string DBgetConnectionString()
    {
        return "server=172.22.45.157;Database=smartlearningdb;Userid=root;Password=;";
    }
```

however,its being unable to open a connection.
**i have a local copy of the database on my laptop if i use `server=localhost`, it works.
**also,if i type 172.22.45.157/phpmyadmin in my browser,i can access the database on his laptop.

what i want is to have the db only on his pc n have everyone able to run the app in the lan.

Comment: I think you miss the port on which the database is exposed. Don't know on which port that is though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable remote conections in your database.

Add this ip or add the symbol %

Like this:

```
mysql> update db set Host='172.22.45.157' where Db='smartlearningdb';
```

`mysql> update user set Host='172.22.45.157' where user='root';`

In phpmyadmin:
[image: phpmyadmin]

Comment: mysql> update db set Host='172.22.45.157' where Db='smartlearningdb';
mysql> update user set Host='172.22.45.157' where user='root';

where would i execute these two lines?

Comment: In mysql console, but if you have phpmyadmin, you can do it in user configuration, adding %, look the image

Comment: i have done the changes as in the picture.still not working..do you think the path in the connection string is wrong?

Comment: You can try to change % for the local ip, of machine you want to connect, % = all conection, 192.168.1.3 = Only this local ip can connect

Comment: This worked for me, you can also set host to "localhost" for another units, and it worked perfectly